# Beta from Crashlytics fail to install build on testers' devices

Tags: ios, testing, provisioning-profile, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

I'm sending my app to testers with [Beta from Crashlytics](http://try.crashlytics.com/beta/) which is an amazing tool to do app testing.

I had every new tester's device UDID registered in my developer account and then distribute a new build.

My testers got email invitation and accessed app's installation which could not be completed on their device. 
They kept seeing an alert showing up with message:

> Unable to download app - MyApp could not be installed at this time -
>   Done / Retry

Testers' testing status are "*installed*" in my Crashlytics dashboard but they're actually not able to finish installation.

Please help me find any possible factor causing this problem.

Comment: Mike from Crashlytics here - there can be a few different reasons why this is happening. Are your testers on iOS 9?

Comment: @MikeB nope they're on iOS 8.3, do you know how to check device log which might record the failed installation process on testers' devices?

Comment: I'm seeing this for one new user now.  Fabric 1.2.8, I don't actually have confirmation that other users are ok, last known successful install was last week.

Comment: Any resolution here?  Looks like all my users are having this problem (starting this week).  Waiting for one to send me device logs...

Comment: We just had this problem too. Uninstalling the current app and re-clicking the link worked for us at least. (Had the 'iOS 8 download fix' switch toggled on for both tries.)

Comment: If anyone is still seeing this, if you can send me the device logs to support(at)fabric.io would be great. To get the device logs:

1) Choose Window -> Devices from the Xcode menu
2) Under the DEVICES section in the left column, choose the device
3) To see crash logs, select the View Device Logs button under the Device Information section on the right hand panel
4) To see the device console, click the up-triangle at the bottom left of the right hand panel to show the device console, then click the down arrow on the bottom right to save the console as a file.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by adding another user and sending out a new build.  Can only speculate as to what caused it based on not examining the install logs myself.  @sharky101 - maybe try adding another user and deploying a build?

Comment: end my case up by simply updating provisioning profile from Xcode > Preferences > Account > choose one > view detail > update ... just the failed build didn't contain a provisioning profile with new registered tester device =p

Comment: @MikeB this still happening to us as well, as there been an identified problem? I just regenerated the provisioning profiles, added users (as suggested above) and uninstalled Crashlytics from my phone. I reinstalled the Crashlytics certificate and tried to install: same problem.

Comment: @bensarz there can be many different reasons for this to happen, but is often an issue around entitlements. If you have the device logs, can you send them to support@ for me to look into?

Comment: My testers are now also getting this - `Unable to Download: APP_NAME could not be installed at this time [Done/Retry options]`

This is on iOS 9 beta 5. Works on all other devices on 8.4. Also worked on this device before this week.

I unfortunately don't have access to the device logs.  Any ideas?

Comment: Im getting this on Android also when using the beta app "App not installed"

Comment: I have similar problem: In my case testers can't install builds with message
"The developer needs to upload a build for this distribution", though build was uploaded successfully. In fabric app all tester's devices for the build are shown with exclamation mark in yellow circle. Provision is valid and ipa file exported for the build can be installed on same devices.

Comment: @GregBair I had the same issue after getting iOS9. This guy's fix solved it for me: https://twittercommunity.com/t/crashlytics-on-ios-9-issues/41180/12

Comment: For me it was the "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements" error which I found in the device logs while trying to install my app.

Comment: Is it a requirement for Fabric Beta distribution, to have an Apple Developer certification, rather than a simple individual AppleID account signing? I am also getting the "Unable to download the app" error, and I'm wondering if this is the cause. My log error is: The bundle being installed with bundle ID <xxx> is authorized by a free provisioning profile, but apps validated by those are not allowed to be installed from this source."

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the provisioning profile embedded in the build has been invalidated. Use Xcode to create a new archive, then use Fabric to upload a new build with that archive.

Discussion:

In my case, I had deleted the provisioning profile in the Apple Developer Member Center that had been embedded in each of my Fabric Beta builds. This caused the app testers had previously installed to immediately crash when they tried to launch it (embarrassing). It also caused the "Unable to download app - MyApp could not be installed at this time - Done / Retry" issue when testers tried to (re)install the app via Fabric Beta. Uploading a new build with my new provisioning profile embedded fixed the issue (each tester had to install the new build).

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this problem back on iOS8 and just recently saw it again for iOS9, the only thing that solved the install issue was for my users to delete any previous version that they had downloaded, restart their phone, and try again.

You can also verify with them if Crashlytics properly installed on their iDevice, I've seen more than once where the configuration profile caused the issue, it's worth removing that (Settings -> General -> Configuration Profile (towards the bottom)) and retrying the install.

Comment: +1 I recently had this problem with iOS 9 too and uninstalling the previous version of the app did it for me as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually caused by one of two problems:

1. Incorrect provisioning profile/code signing settings. Double- and triple-check that the following settings are the same for the project and the provisioning profile: bundle identifier, development vs. distribution, adhoc.
2. Caching - sometimes, even when you've done everything correctly, things still just go awry. In such cases, you can try: deleting the previous version of the app from your phone, cleaning your project, deleting and re-downloading provisioning profiles, and building the app again.

Answer (score 0):

**RubyMotion Solution**

For me, it was because I was using a development distribution profile, but with the wrong entitlements. Well, entitlement, singular.

I still had the 'beta-report-active' entitlement enabled, which was not included with the development distribution profile I am using. It is instead included with the production distribution profile (which is needed to distribute to TestFlight). However, I just wanted to deploy to my local phone, and not air my dirty app laundry to my entire internal test group, so this is where I found myself.

In any case, removing the 'beta-report-active' entitlement fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried the normal route of checking for proper certs and also deleting the app and provisioning profile along with rebooting device. In my case it was installing on device A and not device B. Device A was older iPhone 5c running iOS 9 and device B was newer iPhone 8 running iOS 11.x. When I archived the app for distribution I was selecting device A during the archive. Once I selected "Generic Device" it worked. But I'm sure I've built in the past selecting a specific device instead of generic and it worked. I was using Xcode 8.2, but I don't believe the Xcode version matters.