# Crashlytics fail to install application build on some of the testers' devices using IOS 11.4.1

Tags: ios, react-native, crashlytics

Tester who are using IOS 11.4.1 are unable to run the test builds on their devices, This didn't happen before, after installing the build from beta app this happens
[download problem detected :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcnd5.jpg)

But the application installs on my Device which is also using IOS 11.4.1.
These are the steps i tried for fixing this issue:
1) I checked all the UDIDs (all of the UDIDs were in provisioning profile already)
2) Removed XCode cache, made new build but still same issue
3) Updated the crashlytics to latest version
4) deleted provisioning certificate from apple website and made a new one.
basically followed these Questions but wasn't able to fix this
[Crashlytics with iOS 9 Unable to Download App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31924913/crashlytics-with-ios-9-unable-to-download-app).

[Beta from Crashlytics fail to install build on testers' devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30864835/beta-from-crashlytics-fail-to-install-build-on-testers-devices/35898701)

Comment: Please check the provisioning profile by opening that with textEditor and see the device identifier inside the list, where it is not able to be installed.

Comment: I have checked the provisioning profile already and it has all the UDIDs and updated the provisioning profile multiple times, even changed the profile but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using old version of crashlytics, Maybe it works

Comment: for me using the old version worked, i guess there has been some issue with crashlytics latest build.